# Wamp icon is orange

Tags: wampserver

First, I must say that I'm totally beginner. I installed Wamp server 2 verison (I have XP) but the icon is orange. I have found somewhere that problem is probably in Apache because something using port 80 (probably my skype). Does anyone know how to change that?

Answer (score 27):

What worked for me:

1. Shut down both WAMP and Skype
2. Launch WAMP
3. Launch Skype

Comment: Did'nt know that Skype could interfere with wamp... Thank you so much

Answer (score 8):

Apex is spot on, I don't know how many times I forget about Skype/WAMP conflicting.  As an addition to Apex's answer you can also tell Skype not to use port 80 by going to:

```
Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection
```

and untick **"Use port 80 and 443 as alternative for incoming connections"**

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I reinstalled wampserver without uninstalling first. Uninstalling from the control panel (don't worry, all your database data and www folder files remain intact) then reinstalling fixed the issue.

I also can't stress this enough, UNCOMMENT the "# 127.0.0.1       localhost" line in your C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc hosts file, you may have to set to non read-only to change the file. I can't tell if its because its a slightly newer version of wamp that I'm using now but the difference in speed is unbelievable.

Answer (score 3):

### Other possible fixes:

1) In the tray icons, If under Apache/Service the Start&Stop&Restart were grayed, then there will be "Install service".

2) go to all services (by typing '**services.msc**' in command prompt) and then stop Windows' Web Deployment Agent Service. After that, full restart and it may work.

3) have you installed **vcredits redistributage** before installing WAMP? If not, then uninstall WAMP, install **vcredits redistributage**, then RESTART pc and install WAMP. It may solve.

4)If mysql conflict with Windows:
 click **Windows Button(START)** -->Type/run "**services**"  -->  "Enter") In "Services" window scroll down to MySQL instance, right click and choose stop. Now restart all services on wamp. This may help.

5) Check **system32/drivers/etc/hosts** file, and if there is localhost set to port 80 (or in httpd.conf, if there are apache modules, that are needed)

6) Check apache error logs

Answer (score 1):

If you are running something like Teamviewer then go to your taskmanager then services. Now click on the services icon that will ask for administrative permission. Hit yes.. now find Teamviewer within the service (Hut T and search). Once you find teamviewer right click and then click stop.

Now restart Wamp Server and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

WAMP Server may turn orange for various reason as it is not working. This is also a another type of issue. that can be due to webservices is running in services.msc This is explained in the below blog. Please try it. [How to resolve HTTP Error 404 and launch localhost with WAMP Server for PHP & MySql?](http://techpills.org/node/91)

Answer (score 1):

I just clicked on WAMP Server Icon, then went to Apache, and install service, after that again clicked on its icon, and restart all services, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you install it an unit other than C:

I think there is a bug I think

Check inside

**UNIT:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\extra\httpd-autoindex.conf**

```
Alias /icons/ "C:/Apache2/icons/"

<Directory "C:/Apache2/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

It's harcoded no matter where you install it, then you could change the letter C: for your UNIT: letter, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no conflict on your port 80. then you may just be missing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the antivirus that was creating the problem.
I had Kaspersky installed , and running.

I exited Kasperky from the taskbar, and the icon turned green for me.

If it doesn't turn green on its own, then you can try restarting the WAMP services.

Hope it helps.

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but for the sake of others finding this question with the same problem, here is what worked for me:

In my case it wasn't apache, it was MySQL that was hanging. I was using InnoDB and had uncommented the following lines in my my.ini/my.cnf file:

```
# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir=c:/wamp86/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/data
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir=c:/wamp86/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/data
innodb_log_arch_dir=c:/wamp86/logs
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

After about an hour, I found that the "innodb_log_arch_dir" directive is depreciated in 5.1+, and will cause MySQL to not start.  Here is the [MySQL Bug ticket](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36371) I found that describes the issue.

My solution was to simply comment the line back out.

Hope it helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

For me none of above helped .My problem was caused because I had added end of line comments in httpd.conf once these were removed I had my lovely green Wamp icon again

```
   ScriptAlias /cgi-local/ "c:/intranet/web/cgi-local/" # comment here very bad!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Both programs (Skype and WAMP) use port 80, so you only need to change that port at either program (I prefer Skype).

I got this problem after installing WAMP on Windows 7 (was weird seeing not working), so googled it and found something about Skype and port 80. I only uninstalled Skype, since I didn't even use it that much and that worked. WAMP became green!

So maybe deleting the skype.exe process at ctrl+alt+del, or something like that would also help.

Answer (score 0):

WAMP orange icon solved!
go to C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data and delete ibdata1

Comment: the problem is that it will delete all existing tables in database! be careful!

Comment: Turning the icon red may stop it being orange, but definitely not the right direction! This broke mysql for me

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer of this question if you downloaded MYSQL workbench or something deal with mysql then you need to stop the service because it gets conflict with wamp service so, first you need to press on >>start menu, then second type "Services.msc", then press on the file that will show, then after the "service.msc" is opened type "m" letter and search until you find MySQL then you will see beside MYSQL service the status is started, then right click on MYSQL service and select stop, then go back to wamp and left click on the tray icon and select restart all services, that's it , i hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was with the antivirus avira which block the Host 
i disabled the real time protection and reinstall WAMP 
and it is GREEN

Answer (score 0):

Go to Services ( typing '**services.msc**' in command prompt) and start '**wampapache64**'. This helped me now.

Answer (score -1):

Copied from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon/21678795#21678795)

Before you can fix anything you need to know which service has not started, Apache or MySQL.

As the TEST PORT 80 utility is saying Apache is running its probably the MySQL service that has not started. Unless you have another Apache running!

So which service has not started???

If the wampmanager icon is not GREEN then one of the services ( Apache/MySQL ) has not started properly.

How to tell which service is not running if the wampmanager icon is orange.

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> Apache -> Service If the Start/Resume service menu is Green then Apache IS NOT running.

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> MySQL -> Service If the Start/Resume service menu is Green then MySQL IS NOT running.

If Apache is the service that is not running it is normally, but not always, because something else has captured port 80.

Now do, Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> Apache -> Service -> Test port 80 This will launch a command window and display some information about what, if anything is using port 80.

Whatever it is should be re-configured to not use port 80 or uninstalled if you are not using it.

If port 80 is not the problem look for errors in the appropriate error log ( use the wamp manager menus to view the error logs )

If these do not exists or show no errors then also check the Windows Event Viewer Start -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer And look in the 'Windows Logs' -> Application' section accessed from the menu on the left of the dialog for error messages from Apache and or MySQL.

How to Configure SKYPE so it does not require port 80 or 443

Run SKYPE then using the menus do this: Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection Un-Check the checkbox next to 'Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incomming connections' Now restart SKYPE for these changes to take effect.

If you are running Windows 8 SKYPE comes as an app and this cannot ( as yet ) be configured in this way. However if you uninstall the SKYPE app and install SKYPE in the old way, you can reconfigure it, and it works just as well.