# wampserver doesn't go green - stays orange

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to install wampserver on a win7-32bit. The installation goes smoothly but the icon doesn't turn green. It stays orange saying "Server online". I've trying different solutions nothing worked:
-changed apache port to 8080.
-turn off IIS and other stuff
- even tried to instal xampp server but that didn't work either.

What else is there to do?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post any relevant log files ? error messages ? We need to see something, we are not wizards.

Comment: I don't know what things are relevant, I don't understand much in this stuff. There were no error messages, and log files - what i am supposed to see in them?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11190994/231382

Answer (score 81):

I have had this issue before and it turned out that **Skype** was interferring with port 80. So you may have to look at your system to see if you have another application utilizing this port.

Anyway under Skype, to change this setting it was: `Tools->Options->Advanced->Connection->Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections`. Untick this, restart Skype, restart wamp.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273693/wampserver-2-1-gives-orange-icon-after-install-on-windows-7)

Comment: Just for info, do a test of the port and it will tell you what it is using it... then disable it and works perfectly fine. :)

Comment: perfect, i logged out from skype, restarted wamp and it worked!

Comment: Sometimes after a large Windows update, some services are re-enabled by Windows. In Windows Services you can look for World Wide Web Publishing Service and disable it and prevent it from stating up at boot time. The OP already mentioned IIS, but they changed the name.

Answer (score 49):

If you install WAMPServer before you install the C++ Redistributable, it won't work even after you've installed it because you will miss a critical step in the installation where you tell Windows Firewall to let Apache run.

1. Uninstall WAMP by running the `unins` file in the wamp directory
2. Download and install the vbasic package here [[http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328]](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)
3. Restart your computer
4. Install WAMP again. You should see a message with a purple feather telling you to allow access. Do so, and you should be all good

Comment: This worked for me, i changed the ports on skype, even the http config file to listen to 8080 but stil it did not worked for me, so i uninstalled the wamp server and installed the software given in the above link, than installed wamp again and everything just works fine!

Comment: Lovely. I did the same however it wasnt working cause i forget to restart after .NET updates . My lost green W icon is ready for action again.

Comment: thanks saving my time i installed all pre-req(when we start stepup it show all pre-req links it is about 5,6), after that i installed wamp again then work fine now

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Almost everyone posts the reason as Skype occupying the 8080 port, when the real cause is VC issues, and the re-installation required to make Wamp work. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

the cause could be a variety of reasons.  It might not show up in the log files.
I had the case where the log showed Apache started, then all threads shut down, and absolutely no explanation why. Here's a tip for solving this problem everybody seems to have missed. The log file should show the full command line used to start apache, something like:

```
httpd -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9
```

Do this: open a cmd window, cd to the apache bin directory, and run the command manually:

```
c:\> cd C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin> httpd -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9
```

It blurted out the error stright away; problem solved in 5 minutes:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 609 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/httpd.conf:
CustomLog takes two or three arguments, a file name, a custom log format string or format name, and an optional "env=" or "expr=" clause (see docs)
```

this happened due to a syntax error I put in 'httpd.conf' while trying to make my wampserver multi-homed. But why didn't the apache people write this in the log file?

Comment: Thank you! I found my two problems using this method: a misspelling and and missing directory. You saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

```
click WAMP icon -> Apache -> httpd.conf and find listen 80
```

new versions of WAMP uses

> Listen 0.0.0.0:80
>    Listen [::0]:80
>
> ServerName localhost:80

Change Port Number as you want, like

> Listen 0.0.0.0:81
>    Listen [::0]:81
>
> ServerName localhost:81

and now restart Wamp, thats it

and in web browser type as

> http://localhost:81

Happy Coding..

Answer (score 2):

After trying all the other solutions posted here (Skype, updates to C++ Redistributable), I found that another process was using port 80. The culprit was Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS). You can stop the service from the command line on Windows 7/Vista:

```
net stop was /y
```

Or set the service to not start automatically by going to Services: click Start, click Control Panel, click Performance and Maintenance, click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Services. There, locate "WAS Service" and "World Wide Web Publication Service" and set them to manual or deactivate them completely.

Then restart the WAMP server.

More info: http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/

Answer (score 0):

Also in device manager, first click "show all processes",  put a stop to HTTP

After this fix I got an IIS page issue on localhost which got solved when we did the step below:
Check your hosts file in the C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\ folder, if entry `127.0.0.1 localhost` is commented then uncomment it by removing the # in front of that line.

Answer (score 0):

But if it does not solve the problem, you probably have installed sql 2008 R2, so the solution that worked to me was this [wamp server problems yellow symbol](http://devblog.com.au/wamp-server-problems-yellow-symbol)

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click Xampp Icon
2. Go to TOOLS
3. Then Find Reinstall Services
4. If something pops out which is the windows firewall just allow access.

Then after a minute all should be good :) hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

WAMP Server may turn orange for various reason as it is not working. This is also a another type of issue. that can be due to webservices is running in services.msc This is explained in the below blog. Please try it. [How to resolve HTTP Error 404 and launch localhost with WAMP Server for PHP & MySql?](http://techpills.org/node/91)

Answer (score -1):

Make a Ctrl+Alt+Suppr in order to see if no other Apache version is ever runing on your computer. It was the case for me, I just stop them and the light pass green!

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

My problem was not related to skype as i didn't had it installed. The solution I found was that 2 .dll files(msvcp110.dll, msvcr110.dll) were missing from the directory :

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
```

So I copied these 2 files to all these locations just in case and restarted wamp it worked

```
C:\wamp
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12
```

I hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score -1):

you can run appache:

```
E:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\httpd.exe -d E:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9
```

after that see the log of error and solve it.

Answer (score -1):

**Update 2017- Wamp version 3.0.6**

If you have Installed VC redist from Microsoft but still your wamp icon is orange then it could be a conflict caused by Skype for port #80.

You will need to change port number as explained below.

> Right click on Wamp--> tool--> apache section-->use a port other than
>   80

[image]

Now listen to

http://localhost:7080/phpmyadmin/

Answer (score -1):

If you can't start Wamp anymore right after a Windows update, this is often caused because of Windows that has automatically re-turned on the World Wide Web Publishing Service.

To solve: Click on Start, type Services, click Services, find World Wide Web Publishing Service, double click it, set Startup type to Disabled and click Stop button, OK this dialog and try to restart Wamp.