# WampServer orange icon

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I am having problems with Wamp Server, the icon will never turn green. It is constantly stuck at orange.

I have tried many ways, editing HOSTS file, .config files, disabling IIS, changing SKYPE's port, quitting SKYPE, disabling World Wide Web publishing services etc... And under wamp server icon > Apache > Test port 80, it states that Apache is using that port.

I am running Windows 8 64 bit and Wamp Server 2.4. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which icon? in the system tray?

Comment: try restart option in wamserver

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - Yes, the icon at System Tray.

Comment: @krishna - I have tried that many times but it is still running at orange colour.

Comment: check this.you might get soln http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296882/wamp-icon-is-orange

Comment: @krishna - I have already tried that. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Before you can fix anything you need to know which service has not started, Apache or MySQL.

As the TEST PORT 80 utility is saying Apache is running its probably the MySQL service that has not started. Unless you have another Apache running!

So which service has not started???

If the wampmanager icon is not GREEN then one of the services ( Apache/MySQL ) has not started properly.

**How to tell which service is not running if the wampmanager icon is orange.**

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> Apache -> Service
If the **Start/Resume service** menu is Green then Apache ***IS NOT*** running.

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> MySQL -> Service
If the **Start/Resume service** menu is Green then MySQL ***IS NOT*** running.

If Apache is the service that is not running it is normally, but not always, because something else has captured port 80.

Now do,
Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> Apache -> Service -> Test port 80
This will launch a command window and display some information about what, if anything is using port 80.

Whatever it is should be re-configured to not use port 80 or uninstalled if you are not using it.

If port 80 is not the problem look for errors in the appropriate error log ( use the wamp manager menus to view the error logs )

If these do not exists or show no errors then also check the Windows Event Viewer
Start -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer
And look in the 'Windows Logs' -> Application' section accessed from the menu on the left of the dialog for error messages from Apache and or MySQL.

#### If its MYSQL that has not started.

Check the mysql error log by using the menus

```
wampmanager->MySQL->error log
```

Check the Windows Event log for messages from MYSQL

Check you dont have another MYSQL Server instance running.

**How to Configure SKYPE so it does not require port 80 or 443**

Run SKYPE
then using the menus do this:
Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection
Un-Check the checkbox next to 'Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incomming connections'
Now restart SKYPE for these changes to take effect.

If you are running Windows 8 SKYPE comes as an app and this cannot ( as yet ) be configured in this way.
However if you uninstall the SKYPE app and install SKYPE in the old way, you can reconfigure it, and it works just as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did find the problem after a little more research after posting this question. It was MySQL service that did not start properly, as I had a MySQL client installed which Wamp did not support it's version. I downloaded the MySQL add-on from Wamp's website and installed it and that did the trick.

Comment: Just learned about Event Viewer from Windows, very useful! Thank you

Comment: If in the Apache Services menu there is no way to click start or stop service, you more than likely need to click "Install Service" - this got me up and running!

Comment: Very helpfull. Note that on windows 10, port 80 is used by IIS server. All explained in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758894/apache-server-xampp-doesnt-run-on-windows-10-port-80/#answer-31229606

Comment: Event Viewer solved it for me, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 69):

To add to the above post^^:

If either of the services are not running, it might simply just be because they need to be installed/configured. This is easy to do straight from the WampManager Icon.

---

If **Apache** is not running:

```
 WampManager Icon -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
```

You should get a command prompt pop-up if port 80 is free (if not, see above post):

```
      'Your port 80 is available. Install will proceed.

       Press Enter to continue...'
```

---

If **MySQL** is not running:

```
WampManager Icon -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service
```

---

Do that for one or both services then:

```
WampManager Icon -> Restart All Services
```

The icon should now turn green :)

Comment: This solution worked for me :D Followed "If apache not running". And it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much! I installed both services, and hit "Restart All Services" in the WAMP menu. WAMP restarted with a green icon.

Comment: it didn't work for me as in my case MYSQL is not working

Comment: I have setup Apache to use port 8080 but when I select "Install Service" I see "Your port 80 is actually used by: Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0". Very strange because I've told it not to use port 80 and have restarted multiple times.

Comment: This answer should be on top.  First one get because he answered first..

Comment: This solution worked for me, once it is installed you need to run it.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this same problem this morning but none of the answers above provided me with the solution.

I realised eventually that my issue was because I had changed the DocumentRoot to a subfolder of the www directory, as I had previously been running a Symfony2 project inside www.

With the new project I am working on inside www, that old DocumentRoot dir did not exist any more so Apache failed to start.

wampserver -> Apache -> httpd.conf, then look for "DocumentRoot" and make sure the directory it points to exists or else change it to one that does.

Thank you to RiggsFolly, it was because of your hint about the Event Viewer above that I found the issue.

Comment: I moved my local repository to the c:\wamp\www so that I can test AJAX consistently.  Forgot to change the DocumentRoot!

Answer (score 6):

Wamp server default disk is `"C:\"` if you install it to another disk for ex `G:\`:
go to

1. `g:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\`

2 .call `cmd`

3 .execute `httpd.exe -t`

you will see errors

[image]

4. go to
   `g:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-autoindex.conf`
5. change in line 23 to :

`Alias /icons/ "g:/Apache24/icons/"`

```
<Directory "g:/Apache24/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

6. Restart All services. Done. Resolved

Comment: hey, thanks for the solution. the key was to execute the httpd.exe file. then it shows what is missing. In my case, there was some folders inside www folder that I removed and forgot to remove the directives on httpd-vhosts.conf [C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\extra]. then I removed those directives [VirtualHost tag] in the httpd-vhosts and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

PLEASE NOTE!
If you have gone through all of the above, like "I" did, and still get the Orange icon, and, when you test Port 80 you get "Apache", look at the file:
c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/httpd.conf (your apache version number may differ).

In the file, about line # 62, you'll find a note saying to fill in this:

Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80

Why?

Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.

I changed that to match my localhost IP address and when I restarted Wamp, it quickly went from Red to Green. Success!...3 hours later....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using wampserver 3 (recommended, works with no configuration usually)

- click wampserver icon > apache > service administration > install service
- click wampserver icon > mysql > service administration > install service
- click wampserver icon > mariadb > service administration > install service
- click wampserver icon > restart all services

if this doesnt fix it, try:

- right click wampserver icon > Tools > Check httpd.conf syntax (then fix the issue it identifies and restart all services, likely it's bad syntax in your virtual hosts file)
- right click wampserver icon > Tools > test port 80 (you likely have skype turned on or something else, turn it off and restart all services)

If this doesnt fix it, maybe have a windows conflict:

- [Upgraded to Windows 10 and now WAMP won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713586/upgraded-to-windows-10-and-now-wamp-wont-work/40777260#40777260))

If this doesnt fix it:

- right click wampserver icon > tools

  - check all of those for clues

Answer (score 0):

After removing the innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=4M from my.ini  and killing that process that used the port that Mysql wanted I managed it to go.

Suggested fix:
1) The quick solution: Comment the line
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=4M
in the service's 'my.ini' file,
2) exclude the option from the 5.7.4 default config file or
3) un-unknow the variable to mysql ;)

link: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72533

Use number 1, remove the whole line.
Save to my.ini.
Kill the process if you have one running (look at them with resmon.exe and kill them with command taskkill /pid pid-of-process /f), then start wampmysql and your icon should turn green.

Regards SB

Answer (score 0):

- go to C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17
- look for "my.ini"; right click to edit it

  - use your favorite editor (notepad++, jedit…)
- look for `3306` and change it to `3307`
- restart all the services and it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed both Wampmanager and also  Bitnami's wampstack on your Windows box (like I had done),  make sure Bitnami has not been set to automatically start its wampstackApache and wampstackMySQL services at startup.

To check/fix this, click: Start-->Run and then type services.msc and click Ok.

Select Services  in the list on the left and sort the services on Name.  Scroll to the "w's".   If wampstackApache and/or wampstackMySQL services are already started, right-click and stop both.  Then Restart All Services from the Wampmanager W icon in the windows desktop services tray.  The W should go green.

If this was your problem you can change the default startup behavior to manual start wampstackApache and wampstackMySQL in their Properties tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen because of one of the three reasons:-

1) **Missing VC++ installation:** Install All versions of VC++ redistribution packages VC9, VC10, VC11, VC13, VC14 and VC15. See the link provided at the end for download link. If you have a 64-bit Windows, you must install both 32 and 64bit versions of each VisualC++ package, even if you do not use Wampserver 64 bit.

2) **You forgot to provide Admin Privileges to WAMP Server** : Launch and Install with the **"Run as administrator"** option, very important.

3) **WAMP, IIS and Skype fighting over same port** :

- Close Skype or force not to use port 80: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915
- Disable IIS: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915

[image]

- VC9 Packages (Visual C++ 2008 SP1)

  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092
- VC10 Packages (Visual C++ 2010 SP1)
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523
- VC11 Packages (Visual C++ 2012 Update 4)
  The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
- VC13 Packages] (Visual C++ 2013)
  The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784
- VC14 Packages (Visual C++ 2015 Update 3)
  The two files vcredist_x86.exe and vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:
  http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=53840
- VC15 Redistribuable (Visual C++ 2017)
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746571
  Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2017 x86
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746572

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @Hitesh-sahu said you need all the VC++ redistribution packages for it to turn green. I referred to this [thread](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,149937) from wampserver forum. You can install this little tool (check_vcredist) from the tools section [here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) which will check if all the needed dependencies are installed (see attached image) and it will also provide links to missing ones. If you are using x64 version of Windows like I do and your wampserver does not turn green even after installing all the packages then uninstall and do a fresh installation again. Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case that helps anybody I had the same issue with wampserver3.2.0_x64 on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Tried everything from the answers of this thread and nothing helped.

I then installed wampserver3.1.0_x86 instead and got the green light on first launch. I have no explanation but at least the desired end result.

Answer (score 0):

Please read through the wamp installation carefully, It lists the steps for wamp not turning green clearly. Please read through steps while installing wamp server. It solves most of the bootstrap issues.

Your port 80 is actually used by :
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Modify ports: It works
Appache port from 8080 to 7080
Maria DB port from 3306 to 3307
Mysql DB port from 3308 to 3309

To verify that all VC ++ packages are installed and with the latest versions, you can use the tool:
http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/tools/check_vcredist.exe
Also know the difference between VC++ and VS code

**Visual Studio** is a suite of component-based software development tools and other technologies for building powerful, high-performance applications. On the other hand, **Visual Studio Code** is detailed as "Build and debug modern web and cloud applications, by Microsoft".

[image]