# Upgraded to Windows 10 and now WAMP won't work

Tags: windows, apache, wamp, windows-10

I had WAMP working happily on windows 7 as my local development server. Upgraded to Windows 10 today and had an orange WAMP icon on my taskbar. Turns out Windows had installed and ran IIS automatically (why?).

I disabled IIS, restarted, started WAMP and the icon turned green. However, going to localhost results in a connection refused message. I used the 'Test Port 80' option on the WAMP menu and it says that yes, `Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.10` is listening on port 80.

The Apache error log doesn't display anything helpful.

```
[Wed Jul 29 17:48:40 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 29 17:48:40 2015] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Wed Jul 29 17:48:40 2015] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4200
[Wed Jul 29 17:48:41 2015] [notice] Child 4200: Child process is running
[Wed Jul 29 17:48:41 2015] [notice] Child 4200: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Jul 29 17:48:41 2015] [notice] Child 4200: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Jul 29 17:48:41 2015] [notice] Child 4200: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Jul 29 17:48:41 2015] [notice] Child 4200: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

The Apache access log just displays several instances of

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jul/2015:17:52:47 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 202
```

Any hints, clues, questions to ask on how to proceed? Any way to get more details on why the connection would be refused, and what changed in Windows 10 that would cause it?

Comment: I got the same problem, `net stop WAS` and restarting Apache solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had a static IP before the update. The router port forwarded to it to allow me to use a subdomain of our dns entry to access the dev server. Restoring the static IP configuration solved the problem.

Answer (score 45):

1. Search for "Turn Windows features on or off" on the taskbar.
2. Under "Internet Information Services" deselect "World Wide Web Services" that Microsoft must turn on by default (takes port).
3. Reboot and WAMP came back up as before.

With some windows updates it might occur the need to repeat this operation

Comment: This is the first step I took to get the icon to turn green. IIS is disabled now, I confirmed by using the 'Test Port 80' option that told me it was apache listening on port 80.

Comment: Could you be more specific? How and where should I search for "Control Panel"? I don't see an option "Uninstall programs" anywhere, neither do I see an option "Turn Windows features on or off" etc.

Comment: Can search "Programs and Features" to reach the required screen.

Comment: Reboot is not necessary, just click on WAMP icon and select RESTART ALL SERVICES

Comment: @clod986 Since Windows requests a reboot after the change it's advisable to do so.

Comment: @rybo111 I agree with the fact that is ADVISIBLE. ;)

Comment: @mark  click on start menu, click "Settings".  In the upper right hand
corner there will be a text box. In that text box type in "Turn Windows features on or off". It will show up in the search results on the left.

Comment: Thanks @KenJohnson. After 9 months I finally know where to search for "Turn Windows features on or off" :-) For being so unclear, I down-vote Jack's answer.

Comment: Since `With some windows updates it might occur the need to repeat this operation`, I think a better solution is to leave IIS installed (it is required for me to have it installed anyway...) and simply stop the default web site from IIS Manager (which GUI application so even a child can figure it out). It's simple, fast, easy and you don't have to install/install anything.

Comment: This no longer finds "Turn Windows features on or off"

Answer (score 41):

When I upgraded to Windows 10, Wamp had a port problem with Apache.

Run `cmd` as Administrator, and enter:

```
iisreset /stop
```

Then `Apache > Service > Install Service` will prompt you to press Enter to install as normal.

Once installed `Restart All Services` and you should be up and running.

You may also need to install: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: "Access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer". That is what I got after entering that. I'm on the laptops administration account.

Comment: @WebTechGlobal You must right-click the `cmd` shortcut and select 'Run as administrator'

Comment: the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (version 1607) from August 2016 caused my WAMP to not work at all (red icon). In addition to what @rybo111 said here, in my case I just needed to run `Apache > Service > Install Service` then `MySQL > Service > Install Service` before restarting all services. Didn't need to do a `iisreset` (IIS wasn't running on my machine).

Answer (score 11):

it's working: Enjoy

```
1. Go to Start, type in services.msc
2. Scroll down in the Services window to find the World Wide Web Publishing Service.
3. Right click on it and select Stop.
4. Now restart WAMP and you should be good to go.
```

Remember every time you need to do after restarting your computer... :)

Answer (score 10):

My WAMP icon was RED after upgrading from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

I found the solution here: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134516#msg-134518

> The W10 install will have over wirtten all knowledge of the Apache and MySQL services.
>
> Dont Panic: All you need to do is:
>
> > Start WampServer
> >
> > left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Services -> Install Service
> >
> > left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Services -> Install Service
> >
> > Stop WampServer
> >
> > Start WampServer
>
> It should be fine now.

I didn't have IIS running, and nothing was using my port 80. Didn't even restart the PC, just the above solved my WAMP issues. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Thanks. Finally the answer. I think the issue may have been that I didn't have the c++ distributable installed during initial install of wamp, so these services needed installing manually.

Comment: I can't believe this thing worked out! Don't really know what the reason was, re-installed it, disabled iis, installed bunch of C++ packages... You have a beer from me! Cheers! :)

Comment: I keep on coming here as a ritual, everytime after a windows update

Answer (score 8):

If other answers not work, try running wampserver as administrator.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10

My solution:
You have to remove `wamp` completely, I used `REVO Uninstaller` which remove all files. Check that there is NO Wamp Folder on the C:/ drive. Empty trash bin.

Go to windows and install all the c++ visuals and updates (for what ever system you have).

Restart machine every time it tells you to, download a fresh `wamp` and install.

Start `wamp`, it should go orange.

Go to windows programs (turn features on / off and remove remove IIS service, reboot the machine, restart wamp and bingo it goes green!

I know that this seems along way round but it worked for me after trying all the suggestions on here.

Answer (score 1):

Check you HOSTS file. `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` you will need admin privileges to edit this file.

It should contain at least these lines *without a `#` comment symbol in column 1* :-

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1  localhost
```

plus any entries for Virtual Hosts you may have.

Answer (score 1):

i figured out after many trials that the 32 bit version working perfectly , The 64 version insist not to work

Answer (score 1):

If nothing helped you above like it was the case for me.

Find what is on port 80

```
netstat -aon | findstr :80
```

And kill the pid found

```
taskkill /PID pidFound
```

example:

```
taskkill /PID 1852
```

It was SKYPE...

Have a nice day ;)

Comment: It was skype for me aswell, this comment saved my time. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

If nothing helped you above like it was the case for me.

Find what is on port 80

```
netstat -aon | findstr :80
```

And kill the pid found

```
taskkill /PID pidFound
```

example:

```
taskkill /PID 1852
```

It was Skype for me

Answer (score 1):

If you installed on **Windows**, its common issue you come up with Wamp server since default windows web services (ie IIS) uses your port which is 80.

You could find it with `netstat -aon | findstr :80`

Simple solution is finding another port :) within *1024-49151* 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

since the last update of windows in december(approx 21st dec) i was facing some critical problem and not starting apache is one of them.

I was looking for a proper solution since. so i followed following steps

1) checked service and found wampapache64 service was not starting. tried to start manually with different settings but nothing worked

2) tried removing and installing service of apache from wamp menu but didnt work either

3) so i tried the bellow code in cmd(administrative mode)

cd c:/wamp/bin/apache/ApacheX.X.X/bin
httpd.exe -e debug

it started my apache service

(if this dont start then try step 2 again)

even after all this your apache service dont start right click on wamp icon>tools>restart DNS and then restart wamp

(before the windows update i had set static ip, so it was not working when i removed that ip. the above process allowed access to dynamic ip

this will surely work. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 10 64-bit, running Wamp 2.5 64-bit.

Unfortunately, the above solutions didn't work for my specific problem.  Solutions from other sites failed as well.

However, I was able to fix this by uninstalling the 64-bit Visual C++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 and installing the 32-bit version in it's place.

I re-installed Wamp, and voila - Problem solved.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 have the "World Wide Web Publishing" enabled by default, which is occupying port 80.

Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31884592/209532

Answer (score 0):

Try to put on a CD/DVD first I've done that as well it works better cause it sees it as boot

Answer (score 0):

The aswere provide by @rybo11, working like a charm in windows 10.
Follow this steps:

- Run cmd like administrator
- write this command in terminal: `iisreset /stop`
- Install wamp server 32/64 bit
- Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading all the solutions, and honestly I got lost as I am not that technical. This is my solution: click on the vamp icon (left mouse button) and go with your pointer to apache, once you on appache you will see the httpd.conf file. Open this file and look for the nexy line: Listen 12.34.56.78:80 Listen 0.0.0.80 Listen [::0]:80. Change 80 into i.e. 12. Save the file and restart services. Use localhost:12 as url. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have ISS started, and have a same problem...

Try it: In my case, i use Skype and this problem is caused because the Skype use  80 and 443 ports to accept incoming connections aditionals.

In Skype, click in **Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connections ->** set unmarked checkbox (Use 80 and 443 ports for connections...)

Reboot your Windows, and the WAMPSERVER start all services correctly.

be happy!

Answer (score 0):

Activating `WAMP` after the 2015-2016 update

1. Right click on "This PC" on your desktop and choose "Manage"
2. On the left side select the "Services and Applications"
3. Double click on "Services" in the middle window
4. Scroll down in the Services window to find the World Wide Web Publishing Service. Right click on it and select Stop.
5. Now restart `WAMP` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I got a windows 10 64 bit machine. I simply uninstalled the existing 64bit wamp installed, and installed 32 bit after installing VC++ support.

Now it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: if you have already installed WITHOUT admin. privileges you need to do a reinstall WITH admin. privileges. Less won't do (at least for me).**

What Mohammad Ali Akbari said was the turning point for me, up until that point all I ever got was red. Here's listed my full set of actions (note that some of them might be redundant):

1) [download C++ redistibutable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) like so many others said - I chose 32-bit version (x86) just to be sure as some1 noted it might be an issue using x64

2) make sure IIS is disabled (and no other program occupies port 80) - again as described by so many others (`control panel -> programs and functions -> disable or enable windows functions`), testable by `rightclicking wampserver icon -> tools -> Test port 80`

3) I also manually edited the host file `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` as described by RiggsFolly to uncomment

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1  localhost
```

4) And finally I ran the program with administrator privileges

Result: instant full green icon :)

Hope it helps, and thank you all for this thread!

Answer (score 0):

Left click on the `Wamp icon > Localhost`.

If this brings up the `WampServer` page, Apache is running.

If you can't get to the `WampServer` page, then you should left click on the `Wamp icon > Apache > Service`.

If all options there are grayed out except `Install Service` and `Remove Service`, then click `Install Service`.

Left click on the `Wamp icon > Restart all services`.

Click `phpmyadmin` under the `Tools` heading. If you get an error like (`#2002`), then there is likely a problem with your MySQL installation.

Left click on the`Wamp icon > MySQL > Service`.

If all options there are grayed out except `Install Service` and `Remove Service`, then click `Install Service`.

Left click on the `Wamp icon > Restart all services`.

This fixed the problem for me and I hope it does for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

easy way to fix click wamp icon than click Apache and from there click httpd.conf and open it and find this line in file

## Listen 12.34.56.78:80

Listen 80

change this to

## Listen 12.34.56.78:81

Listen 81

now restart wamp services
now in browser window you can access localhost by typing this

localhost:81

Answer (score 0):

Ig you have Skype running close it and restart all services!

Answer (score 0):

I install wamp and visual C++ which is required for windows 10 but my wamp is orange. I just follow these step.
1 - Left click on wamp icon >> Apache >> Services
2-Click on Install services
3- Stop and restart wamp server

and it turn to green. 
one more thing you need to check if you are using skype.
Open skype 
1Tool>>Option>>advance>>Connection
Uncheck the port 80 it by default selected.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up WAMP on Windows 10
I struggled with this for 2 days and finally found a very simple solution.

1. I completely uninstalled WAMP. After messing with it for 2 days, I wanted to make sure to start over with "factory settings."

   2. I downloaded a new copy of WAMP. During the install process it told me that a WAMP folder already existed, and asked if I still wanted to install it there. I said yes.
   3. I opened notepad as an administrator. I navigated to HOSTS file.  C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
      I removed the '#' comment from these 2 lines.
      127.0.0.1  localhost
      ::1   localhost
   4. I saved the file, and bingo! Worked like a charm. WAMP worked exactly as it was supposed to after that. And BTW, I didn't have to change any port settings.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I use WAMP x64 version and had an issue of apache not starting, this I fixed by installing [Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679). After a restart apache was working again.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by stopping a service
SQL Server Reporting Service(SQLEXPRESS)
and 
install apache service.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **VMWare** -> just go to windows services (type services in search bar)
and right-click on **VMware Authorization Service** (from list) and at the end select **stop**. Now try to start apache again.

Answer (score -1):

You need to fix your httpd.conf and alias configuration files.
Here is a description how to solve it:
https://www.hieule.info/web/solve-the-denied-access-problem-when-using-wamp-server-2-on-windows-8/#comment-12822

Logical and it works for Windows 10 (Home Basic)