# WAMPServer not working properly on Windows 10, "could not perform service action"

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver, windows-10

Recently I have upgraded from windows 7 64 to windows 10 64.
Before that I've had WAMPServer running like a charm, but now it doesn't work.
Whenever I launch it I get the server offline. Clicking on the "put online" results only in getting the "could not perform service action" error pop up.
I have already tried reinstalling Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4, renaming the localhost and listen from 80 to 8080, turning off skype, none of these worked.

Does anybody know of a different solution to fixing this error?

Comment: Find below link where you will find solution for your question :) [Wamp server on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713586/upgraded-to-windows-10-and-now-wamp-wont-work/43828377#43828377)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should also check the HOSTS file. It comes empty I think in W10.

Make sure you have at least

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1  localhost
```

*without '#` comments in column 1*

Also you may well have inadvertantly installed IIS. MS seem to think this is a good idea lately. Check and if you are not using it, uninstall it.

Comment: I did what you said. Now wamp shows that it's online (the icon is still red tho), yet when I go on localhost in my browser the window is still blank.
I have checked the processes and found IIS worker process.
Would ending it remove the issue?

Comment: Look at the Windows Event View for messages from MYSQL and Apache ALso look at the APache error log and the mysql error log

Comment: Nvm found it. There are 3 MySql, and 4 Apache errors repeating:
MySql: Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory, Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ? and Aborting

Apache: (...) AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 ,  AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 ,     AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down   and AH00015: Unable to open logs     .

Comment: UPDATE: Changing the data in httpd of apache in the way Want2bExpert said, got rid of all the apache errors.The icon is now orange, still not working.

Comment: UPDATE2: Disabling the mysql process made the icon green, and the server is on line....still getting white page on attempting access

Comment: Ok, after deleting iis and reinstalling wamp it FINALLY WORKED. Thanks for all the help. The answer is yours.

Comment: thanks a lot @RiggsFolly....it worked for me. the issue is solved by adding above lines in the `hosts` file...

Answer (score 16):

Stop IIS if not require. It is working for me.

1. Open cmd.exe by Run as administrator
2. Type `iisreset /stop` then hit enter
3. Restart wamp Server
4. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you, this sorted my issue out. Also, this post may be useful to some [https://forums.iis.net/t/1227982.aspx?IIS+10+0+in+Windows+10+Pro](https://forums.iis.net/t/1227982.aspx?IIS+10+0+in+Windows+10+Pro)

Comment: Usually developers prefer to use IIS and wamp together. So, stopping will not solve the problem. If one wants to use both together, change the port of apache. I have mentioned the steps in an answer below.

Answer (score 11):

All you need to do is install the Apache and MySQL services.

Start WampServer

left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Services -> Install Service
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Services -> Install Service

Stop WampServer
Start WampServer

Comment: been working on this, looking for WWWP etc, checking port 80, disabling skype, googling and binging over and over. THANK YOU

Answer (score 5):

These above comments did not fix the issue with WAMP for my computer using Windows 10, however, I did find the answer to my problem from: 
http://praveenpuglia.com/make-wamp-work-on-windows-10-technical-preview/

World Wide Web Publishing Service was using the Port 80, causing WAMP to not work properly.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to Start, type in services.msc
- Scroll down in the Services window to find the World Wide Web Publishing Service.
- Right click on it and select Stop.

Comment: Remember, you will have to do this every time you reboot your PC.

Answer (score 1):

Worked very well. left click wamp icon on the task tray -> apache -> service administration ->install service...

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggested that you didn't upgrade to.windows 10 as operating usually have bugs at early launch. 
Next time run new Operating system on Virtual PC first before going for full.system upgrade.
Change the port number to e.g. 8084? If available because 80 still 8080.

Answer (score 0):

It's working: Enjoy

```
1. Go to Start, type in services.msc
2. Scroll down in the Services window to find the World Wide Web Publishing  Service.
3. Right click on it and select Stop.
4. Now restart WAMP and you should be good to go.
```

Remember every you need to do, after restarting computer.... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually issue caused by clash in http ports.
IIS already takes port no 80 and apache tries to take 80 and clash happens.

Start apache with other port and it will run:

Step 1:
Stop wamp services.
Close wamp manager

Step 2:
\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf
Change Port to 8080 (or any other free port)

Step 3:
\wampmanager.tpl
Note: Changing in wampmanager.ini does not work as its regenerated from .tpl file
change set the port you have selected above to localhost.

e.g.
http://localhost to http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue intermittently and i found out it was Skype. Closing Skype and restarting all services in WAMP fixed the issue for me. If you have other means of instant messengers open, try closing those too. You need to free up port 80.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I was using Wamp x86 and my Windows 10 is X64. It could be working but it was not. Then, I installed Wamp x64 and it's working normally now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Start, type in services.msc
2. Scroll down in the Services window to find the World Wide Web Publishing  Service.
3. Right click on it and select Stop.
4. Double click on World Wide Web Publishing and set "Startup Type" to "Manual"
5. Restart WAMP

People are missing step 4 to prevent having to stop the service after every restart. Pretty sure its in the instructions when installing the latest version of WAMP, but just noting it here in case someone is reading some of the above comments mentioning this method.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem `smdrhk.biz` i use:Go to Start, type in services.msc
Scroll down in the Services window to find the World Wide Web Publishing Service.
Right click on it and select Stop.
Double click on World Wide Web Publishing and set "Startup Type" to "Manual"
Restart WAMP

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it simple.

1. Go to the task bar -> click on Wamp icon ->apache->httpd.conf.
2. find -> Listen [::0]:80 change it into Listen [::0]:8080 (save it)
3. right click on wamp Icon and click exit.
4. Go to C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql(version)\data -> delete ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and auto.cnf files.
5. restart Wamp and enjoy it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**This is for the 02-2020 update.**

Previously my Wamp Server was working fine and later it suddenly stopped working and I tried all the solutions above but none has helped me. I finally solved it by reinstalling the WAMP server. So my suggestion for everyone would be, instead of trying various solutions to make it work and you dont know whether you would get the solution or not. You never know how much amount of time you would waste when trying this all things. My suggestion would be ,copy all the files that are already in the server including the database. Try to reinstall the server. It will surely work.

**List of options I tried and failed**

1. Changed the port numbers.
2. Tried this command iisreset /stop.
3. Tried stopping this by going to services.msc on RUN -> World Wide Web Publishing
   Service ( but my system doesn't show this World Wide Web Publishing Service).
4. Tried restarting the Wamp server more than 10 times after trying all the options

The above options may or mayn't work. This is only my suggestion and explained you based on my expereince.

**Thanks**

Answer (score -3):

1. open `run`
2. write `Services.msc`
3. go to `World Wide Web Publishing`
4. then click on `Stop`
5. Restart Wampserver