# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003) error phpmyadmin using MAMP on windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a database for a PHP project using MySQL in phpmyadmin and also using MAMP on windows 10 and after I create the database and create a new user and try to check the database connection..it shows the below error..

Database connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)

I did check relevant questions in the forums and tried all the tricks there but did not work..

I am mostly a Wordpress developer and I am able to create a new database in wordpress like before but PHP is giving me issues..

Please check my codes..

config.php

```
 <?php

    // Database Constants
    defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
    defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "pop234");
    defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "4JfQuuQnzU6yfPdm");
    defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "demo");

    ?>
```

database.php

```
<?php

    require_once ('config.php');

    class MYSQLDatabase {

        private $connection;

      function __construct() {
        $this->open_connection();
      }

      public function open_connection() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          die("Database connection failed: " . 
               mysqli_connect_error() . 
               " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
          );
        }
      }
    }

    $database = new MySQLDatabase();
    $db =& $database;

    ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

require_once('../includes/database.php');

if(isset($database)) { echo "true"; } else { echo "false"; }
echo "<br />";

?>
```

I have also tried using 127.0.0.1:8889 instead of localhost like i do in my WP programs if I get a database error..

Please assist and advise

Thanking you in anticipation..

```
<?php

// PHP Database Constants
defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "popat234");
defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "4JfQuuQnzU6yfPdm");
defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "demo");

// Wordprsss Database Constants
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'demo');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'popat234');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '4JfQuuQnzU6yfPdm');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:8889');

?>
```

Comment: Did you make sure that your MySQL is running?

Comment: I tried to look it up in services but could not find it and so i tried to see if I can get a database connection for Wordpress and i was successful so i think that if it was not running i should have failed here also..Am i rite?

Comment: Can you please clarify how you created the database if the Mysql server is not accessible?

Comment: i created the database from phpmyadmin available under localhost:8888/MAMP

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my point.  Check your Wordpress configuration (`wp-config.php`) to see the difference with what you put in your `config.php`.

Comment: identical..its just that wordpress sometimes gives database error with localhost so i have to put in 127.0.0.1:8889 and i tried that also in config.php but it still gives the error..

Comment: There must be a difference you're not seeing.  Wordpress doesn't have any magic tricks and neither does PHPmyadmin.  You should probably include it in your post.

Comment: please check the edited question and I have added the two config.php at the end..

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774958/wampserver-not-working-properly-on-windows-10-could-not-perform-service-action

Comment: I am using MAMP dear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DB_USER` is different in the two configurations.  `config.php` shows 'pop234' and `wp-config.php` uses 'popat234' which is apparently the correct one.

Make sure that your `config.php` contains:

```
 <?php

    // Database Constants
    defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "127.0.0.1");
    defined('DB_PORT') ? null : define("DB_PORT", "8889");
    defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "popat234");
    defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "4JfQuuQnzU6yfPdm");
    defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "demo");
```

Also correct your `mysqli_connect()` line to:

```
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);
```

Comment: actually i tried with popat234 also..it did not work..this i have put by error but it does not work in either case

Comment: Try running the updated config.php I just edited to be really sure you're not doing a tiny mistake.

Comment: Database connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:8889' (0) (2005)

Answer (score 0):

try to switch your port from 8889 to 3306, this resolve my problem. This maybe can occurr because the Windows block the port 8889.