# Windows 10 - WAMP Orange

Tags: wamp

I've installed WAMP 64bit server on my windows 10 enterprise machine. However I'm getting a orange icon. I've checked the following:

1. Apache -> Service, the start/resume service is greyed out and stop service is red. In addition Test Port 80 gives me:

Your port 80 is actually used by :
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12

2. Mysql -> service, start/resume service is green. When I click on it nothing happens.
3. I've tried turning off the windows firewall, nothing happens.
4. I've checked for skype but it is actually not installed on my machine. Tried netstat-b in the command prompt and I can't see anything with port 80
5. Searched for mysql-bin.index to delete but nothing came up.

Any help on what I can try next will be grateful. Thanks

UPDATE
Following RiggsFolly advice below are the erros I am getting from MySQL via the windows event logger:

```
    2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-08 08:31:08 18ec InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-08 08:31:08 18ec  InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [ERROR] InnoDB: File C:\wamp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0: 'aio read' returned OS error 187. Cannot continue operation
```

Also from googling I tried adding the following line to my.ini file, but still get the same error:
innodb_flush_method=normal

Comment: This looks like the MYSQL Service has not started if what you report is correct. Look at the `mysql error log` `wampmanager->MySQL->error log` what does that report **edit question with contents** If that is empty and I guess it will be then look at the `Windows Event Log` for errors from `MYSQL`

Comment: You could also check that the MYSQL Service has been correctly registered. Using the services snapin check that the service called `wampmysqld64` exists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the windows event log and this is the error:The wampmysqld64 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 14 time(s). Also the MYSQL log is empty

Comment: Is that all there is, no other associated messages explaining why? Edit you question and add one of each MYSQL error message from the Event Log to you question.

Comment: Thanks Riggs I've updated windows event logger as requested.

Comment: I've concluded it is a MySQL issue not WAMP/XAMPP. So I decided to start another question focusing on this issue.Link below. I will likely delete this post in a day. NEW POST http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888044/windows-10-enterprise-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Answer (score 17):

In Windows 10 Microsoft decided to enable the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" (a webserver) by default.

Try and run in cmd:

```
netstat -aon | findstr :80
```

And see something like:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  ...
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::1]:80               [::1]:50558            ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    [::1]:50558            [::1]:80               ESTABLISHED     11504
```

You know you have another service blocking port 80.

**Solution:**

Start -> Type "Services" -> Enter -> Find "World Wide Web Publishing Service" -> Select it -> Right click -> Properties -> Change Startup type: Automatic to Manual and click the Stop bottom -> Apply/OK.

Now you can right click on you WAMP icon and click "Restart All Services".

**Viola!**

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried the cmd netstat -aon|findstr :80 I only get TCP    192.168.0.10:49556     23.205.116.42:80       ESTABLISHED     1884. As to my question I have no issues getting Apache working on Port 80, 443. Its only the MySQL part. Also I checked the services there is no World Wide Web Publishing Service installed nor running. Finally making sure it is not WAMP I installed XAMPP and I'm getting the same error. I've updated my questions with all the errors in the MySQL_error.log

Answer (score 8):

I know this thread is a bit old but I found a solution to my problem.
From the WAMP icon, navigate to:

- wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
- wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service

When Apache failed for me, it suggested that Skype might be the problem, because it was utilizing the requisite ports. I quit Skype, restarted all WAMP services, and got the green light... or green W rather ;)

Comment: This worked for me too. It turns out windows firewall had blocked the service. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

Change the port WAMP is using. By default, WAMP uses port 80. You can change the port by: right click WAMP > tools > "Use port other than #"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks , This helped