# Windows 10 Enterprise - MYSQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, wamp

I've installed Windows 10 Enterprise 64bit on machine and attempting to install Apache, PHP and MySQL on my machine to use for web development. In short I keep running into an error "MySQL shutdown unexpectedly". I've attempted to install using WAMP and XAMPP on my machine and still run into the same error. Apache connects and works on both WAMP and XAMPP however I get the same MySQL error.

So far from all the research I've done please find a synopsis of my situation and the solutions I've tried. I'm thinking this is to do with Windows 10. Also as a side note I'm using bootcamp on my MacBook 12 inch so not sure if this adding to the problem but I would not have thought so.

1. Apache running on port 80:433 for both XAMPP and WAMP
2. WAMP - Mysql -> service, start/resume service is green. When I click on it nothing happens. XAMP I get:

   8:50:59 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

   8:50:59 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,

   8:50:59 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

   8:50:59 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

   8:50:59 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

   8:50:59 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this

   8:50:59 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
3. Turned off windows firewall, same errors

4.I've checked for skype but it is actually not installed on my machine.Also checked control panel -> view local services, skype is not there nor running Tried netstat-b in the command prompt and I can't see anything with port 80. Also tried netstat -aon | findstr :80, only TCP 192.168.0.10:49556 23.205.116.42:80 ESTABLISHED 1884. Note: If the port was an issue Apache should not be working

5. I checked the control panel -> view local services there is no World Wide Web Publishing Service.
6. Followed solution in [Xamp-Mysql Shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly) which included deleting ib_logfile1, ib_logfile and ibdata1. As well as appending my.ini with innodb_force_recovery = 1. I get a slightly different error which I put below.

I'm pretty much out of options and about to give into the fact that MySQL may not work on my windows 10 machine. But before I do any help would be appreciated.

Error Logs:

```
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-08 08:31:08 18ec InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-08 08:31:08 18ec  InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2015-08-08 08:31:08 7024 [ERROR] InnoDB: File C:\wamp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0: 'aio read' returned
```

Error Log @ innodb_force_recovery = 1

```
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-08 09:32:05 1bf8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
2015-08-08 09:32:05 1bf8  InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2015-08-08 09:32:05 3804 [ERROR] InnoDB: File C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101: 'aio write' returned OS error 187. Cannot continue operation
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think this is also not a "programming language" also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly?rq=1

Comment: try setting `innodb_flush_method=normal` in your my.ini file under `[mysqld]` and restarting...

Comment: Did you bother to look up error 87? `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER The parameter is incorrect.` And OS 187 = `ERROR_SEM_NOT_FOUND 187 (0xBB) The specified system semaphore name was not found.` Try turning of your Virus Checker temporarily. Does it start then?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. BK435 I have tried innodb_flush_method=normal I get the same error. Riggs, no haven't tried turning off the virus scanner (windows defender) will give it shot!

Comment: @Altius: I agree. Thanks for pointing it out. (_tu quoque_ won't help you here)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

1. Uninstall XAMPP and WAMP
2. Installed WAMP 64bit
3. Added the following line to my.ini 
   innodb_flush_method=normal
4. Closed WAMP and restarted. Logo W is green and working.

Thank you to: [Error 187](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461872/configuration-of-mysql-server-installation-failed-or-cant-start-the-service)