# Wamp Server Working But Still Orange

Tags: apache, wamp

No, this is not a duplicate question!

Wamp Server doesn't start on system boot up. 
When I turn it on, it is in Orange but it works just fine and Test Port 80 says that it is used by Server: Apache and PHP.

I have to `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Del` < Task Manager < (2) Apache Httpd Servers 
Then end both tasks.
Then Restart All Services and Wamp will be green!

My questions are 
 1. if it works then why is it in orange? 
 2. can I make it start on system start?

Note: MySQL Server is working properly at all time.

I don't have Skype installed and I don't think the problem is with the ports...

I have already tried uninstalling then re-installing but that didn't fix the problem.

EDIT: 
According to the solution @RiggsFolly suggested, I can see that Apache is not starting properly; however, weirdly the web app can be run normally...

Comment: First have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon/21678795#21678795 to help you decide which service is not starting the first time you start WAMPServer. Then edit your question letting us know which service is not starting.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's Apache that is not starting properly; however, the web app is working normally...

Comment: As I suspected - you have 2 web servers running. The other one is I assume starting Automatically at boot. I would suggest uninstalling the other Apache and also checking you dont have another MySQL running also

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did a clean reinstallation: 1.uninstall  2.reboot system  3.clean registry and leftovers  4.reboot again  5.install  6.reboot one last time

Now it's working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can also change the port as well. yes you can start wamp service on system start by setting in start up program MSConfig can be used to configure several things other than just startup programs.

Comment: if you could give a detailed answer so that you help me and future viewers, I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: Log in as an administrator.

    Start -> Run "services.msc"

    Right click the service wampapache (may also be called wampapache64). Go to properties and set start-up type to 'Automatic'

    If you want MySQL to also be available on startup, then repeat step 3 for wampmysqld (or wampmysqld64)