# WAMP Server MySQL won't come online

Tags: wamp, wampserver

When I try to start WAMP, it loads, but stays orange.

By left-clicking WAMP, then going to MySQL->Service, I can see that the Start/Resume is green, indicating it's MySQL that didn't start.  (Apache appears to have started)

MySQL v 5.6.17

I've looked up the error logs below, but haven't found anything useful.

```
[Thu Feb 25 15:02:04.507685 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7344:tid 708] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Feb 25 15:02:04.508184 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7344:tid 708] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:13:13
[Thu Feb 25 15:02:04.508184 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7344:tid 708] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Thu Feb 25 15:02:04.515686 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7344:tid 708] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 12348
[Thu Feb 25 15:02:05.487426 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12348:tid 588] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

**MySQL Error log:**

```
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1598839555 and 1598839555 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1598839565 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-03-02 13:05:25 52448 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysite1/cache uses space ID: 10 at filepath: .\mysite1\cache.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysite2/my_table which uses space ID: 10 at filepath: .\mysite2\my_table.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysite2\my_table.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Comment: Start by checking this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon/21678795#21678795 then let us know which service is actually causing the issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly - ah!  Makes sense!  I've used that to update my question.

Comment: Now look in the MYSQL Error Log `wampmanager -> MYSQL -> ErrorLog` if that is empty then look at the Windows Event Viewer for messages from MYSQL Indicating an error

Comment: @RiggsFolly - done.  Added MySQL error logs.  I tried finding nay .idb files, but can't anywhere.  Also can't find a 'my.cnf' file.

Comment: Well that is quite self explanitory. You have a corrupted INNODB database. follow the instructions to see if you can recover it. Or the simple solution is to restore your last backup _For `my.cnf` read `my.ini`_

Comment: @RiggsFolly - maybe it's self explanatory to you, but I'm lost.  As mentioned, I can't find ANY .idb files, so that makes #2 no help.  And I also can't find any "my.cnf" file.  I checked the "my.ini" file, but there is no "innodb_force_recovery" in it.  I'm unsure what #1 is even referring to.

Comment: `my.ini` has no `innodb_force_recovery` in it because it is not something you leave in there. When trying to recover a database YOU add it in there. There is no __one answer fits all__ for an INNODB database corruption recovery. You will have to start learning the correct way to manage an INNODB database and How to recover one http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html If you had a backup, that would be the simple answer, if you dont you have learnt a valuable lesson. I suggest you read the MYSQL INNODB manual carefully before attempting any actual recovery

Comment: I'm not asking how to recover a database.  I'm just asking how to get WAMP going again.  I really don't need to learn how to manage an INNODB - that's not my job and I don't have time for it at the moment.  If it comes down to just completely uninstalling WAMP, then that's what I'll do.  Was just hoping for an easier way.  Apparently there isn't one :/