# Wamp Server is always orange due to an error in MySQL service

Tags: mysql, wampserver

My Wamp Server was working perfectly well until yesterday when I started the mysqld from the command line and went on to import a .sql file from the MySQL console. The WAMP icon stays orange all the time. There is no issue with the Apache service but the issue is with the MySQL service. When I looked for wampmysqld service on services.msc, it doesn't show any. But when I run mysqld from the command line, it works fine.

Itried several methods but none of them worked. I also tried installing Wamp Server 2 as an addon but it didn't work for me, and now I can't select the version of MySQL even.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Have you tried changing the port number?

Comment: Refer : [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21678795/2142994)

Comment: @AniMenon yes I referred that and there's no issue in the port number, it says port 3306 is listening.

Comment: @AniMenon That post is more to do with deciding which service is not starting and if it is Apache, how to go about fixing it. But thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have 2 MYSQL Servers running.

Check the Event Viewer for messages from MYSQL.

Check the services, wampservers MYSQL is called `wampmysqld64`, if you have another running it will probably be called `MYSQL`

If this is the case, you will either have to uninstall the other MYSQL or at least Stop it in the services snapin, or disable it, if you are sure it was a mistake uninstall whatever brought this other MYSQL to your party

What did you install recently, some apps bring their own mysql instance for example some installs of `MySQL Workbench` will install an instance if you pick the full with everything version.