# Wamp icon is orange and Apache isn't working because Port 80 is being used by... Apache?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, port80

Title says it all. I believe it is a problem with Apache.

Skype is turned off and I have already changed some ports from 8080 to 80, so it's none of that.

As for the Apache Services, first of all the Start/Resume button is inactive.

If I ask to Test Port 80, I get the following message:

> Your port 80 is actually used by :
>
> Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12
>
> Press Enter to exit...

If I click on Install the Services, I also get that:

> Your port 80 is actually used by :
>
> Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12
>
> Cannot install the Apache service, please stop this application and try again.
>
> Press Enter to exit...

I just don't understand the problem and could not find anything to tell me how to solve it. Who knows? Maybe it has nothing to do with Apache.

So yeah... Help, please!

Comment: Did you have a previous instalation of wamp/xamp ?

Comment: @KA_lin Nope. This is the same one I had and for the first time on this machine. It just decided to stop working after a while of me not using it.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the apache service (and any related) and start normally?

Comment: Just did that. Still getting the same problems

Comment: Are you sure Skype is not running?

Comment: If you want we can try on TeamViewer but we will have to talk here until the page tells us that we should have a private conference

Comment: Run command prompt as administrator, and then execute the following command `net start`. It'll list all active services. Find the name apache service has, and then stop it using `net stop <apache-service-name>`. Try running WAMP again.

Comment: @KA_lin sure, I've never used team viewer before, I will get it installed so we can try that out. That would be lovely.

Comment: @hjpotter92 This may sound stupid, but I don't think I am getting the name of the apache service right. I thought it would be apache2.4.9 or Apache/2.4.9 but it says the service name is invalid. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Lets start from the beginning:

Your statement: *first of all the Start/Resume button is inactive.*

This normally means that the Apache service is running *you dont want to start/resume it if its running*

If the Post 80 test says

> Your port 80 is actually used by :
>
> Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12

This normally means that Apache **is actually running**

The WAMPServer apache service is called ***wampapache***

If Apache is running there **is no point trying to install the service as its already installed**

## So the problem is not APACHE

#### So what is the problem

#### Well if the icon is Orange, and Apache is running then the issue must be with MYSQL

**Look at the MYSQL Error Log**

```
left click wampmanager->MYSQL->Error log
```

> Or read this answer [WampServer orange icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon/21678795#21678795)