# Wamp Server error - php

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I setup **Wamp Server** in **D:/** Driver not **C:/** Driver and i created a folder inside **WWW** Folder with the name of **php_course** and inside it i created php file named **test.php** and  when i tried to run the php file using 
**localhost/www/php_course/test.php**

this problem appeared 
[the problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpvc7.jpg)
Should i setup Wamp in C:/ or change something in Wamp settings ?

Comment: https://www.slideshare.net/triniwiz/wamp-20949805 try this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon/21678795#21678795

Answer (score 0):

Hello_

First, where did you installed WAMP has nothing to do with your problem :)

The error **404** that you see means that server is not able to find what you are looking for at the specified path.

**localhost** is referring to **www** folder.

Then if you want to make request to your **test.php** which is in **php_course**
folder you should simply call it like this:

> localhost/php_course/test.php

No need of specifying **www** in the path because actually **localhost** is referring to **www** folder(with default WAMP configuration).

For example if you put file **test.php** in **www** folder you will do a request to this file like this:

> localhost/test.php

That's it. Have fun with WAMP :)

Comment: I'm entering the same URL which is localhost/php_course/test.php and i tried to copy the php file to WWW Folder and went to localhost/test.php but still have the same problem

Comment: Do you see WAMP default page if you request just `localhost`. Is WAMP taskbar icon green?

Comment: @mohamedahmed now I see the picture once again and I can say that your request is processed from **IIS** and not **WAMP**. Check this page https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635851(v=ws.11).aspx how to stop **IIS** and then start your **WAMP** again