# Wampp is not turning into green even after changing the port

Tags: apache, wamp

Everything was working fine but suddenly the wampp stops turning into green. I have watched many tutorial every one is saying to change the port I have done that but still no progress. 
Any one please help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon/21678795#21678795

Comment: Thank a lot. I have uninstalled and installed it again. Now it is working well.