# php dosent execute the command and instead returns the code

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, wamp

i am trying to code a forum in php but whenever i try to register it returns the code i typed:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

echo "register info : ";
echo $username. ;
echo $password. ; ?>
```

(this isn't the final code and is just a test to see if the code is working) but it should return what i inputted into the text box' for the username and password.

also dont know if this helps but the "wamp localhost server" i set up also isnt working i tried changing the port multiple times

Comment: if that's your real syntax; you can't just inject PHP into HTML markup tags like that.

Comment: I'm also wondering if you're trying to run this off as `file:///` rather than an explicit `http://` protocol(?). So, are you?

Comment: [Your starter for 1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: The HTML/form is missing here, and details as to the server information. Check for errors; error reporting is there at your disposal, including `phpinfo()`.

Comment: i cant run in http:// because when i try my localhost server http://localhost:3306/ i get "This page isn’t working
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE"

Comment: 3306 is almost certainly your MySQL server. You must run PHP code through the PHP interpreter to execute it. file:// will not work.

Comment: i looked it turned out to be localhost:3308 but that still didnt work

Comment: JUST USE `localhost` the default is PORT 80, ___as for ANY web server___ and you dont need to add that

Comment: it is not the default port because thats the default for Apache not MySQL also just typing localhost took me to microsoft.com

Comment: Correct, well you need to use Apache ( the web server  ) When you come to use the database ( MySQL) you do that from within your PHP script, not via the URL in the browser

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /forum.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) PHP/5.6.35 Server at localhost Port 8000

Comment: Order of operations `browser > http://localhost > Apache > PHP > MySQL` In your Wamp Apache configuration check to ensure you have a configured virtualhost for your localhost, and `mod_php` is enabled. Otherwise your PHP code example will not help us to resolve the issue of it not working in your browser. Otherwise you would need to open a command line terminal and execute `php c:\wamp\www\path\to\script.php`

Comment: Well if you moved Apache to listen on port 8000 use `localhost:8000` But WHY did you move it to port 8000

Comment: because thats the port brackets suggested also i did put loaclhost:8000

Comment: But it just causes these kind of problems! And who or what is `brackets`

Comment: the question is "what is brackets" and the answer is the software i use for web code

Comment: also wamp turns orange when the port is set to 80

Comment: Ah well that at least thats a reason. I expect you have IIS installed. If you are not using it, uninstall it (MS for some reason install it on W10 by default) then Apache will be able to use port 80 as it should

Comment: im using windows 7

Comment: Ok then the next most likely thing is that SKYPE is using port 80. You can reconefigure SKYPE  in which case [have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon/21678795#21678795), to find out how to reconfigure SKYPE so it does not use port 80 or 443

Comment: Or just dont start SKYPE until you have started WAMPServer. SKYPE will then work out that it canot use port 80 and use another port automatically

Comment: i disabled IIS and Skype hasn't been opened on my computer in months, also do i need VS installed?

Comment: Not Visual Studio itself, but you do need all the MSVC Runtimes installed. See the post called `WAMPServer 3 All you need to know` on the [WAMPServer Help forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2)

Answer (score 1):

PHP code has to be wrapped in a php tag like this.

You start the interpreter with a `<?php` and you stop it using `?>`

```
<p>
<?php
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    echo "register info : ";
    echo $username;
    echo $password;
?>
</p>
```

Comment: Bit of a Saturday treat.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Well you closed my last attempt at `Low Hanging Fruit` 10 seconds before I had finished typing the answer so thanks for the UV

Comment: It seems that this goes deeper, much deeper than any rabbit hole I've ever seen.

Comment: i did put <?php at the start and ?> at the end

Comment: I dont see it in your question?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner How did you know that, before the comment was made. You are starting to frighten me a little. But thanks for the Rabbit Warren Warning

Comment: Call me "clairvoyant", or just "experienced" ;-) @Riggs in any case; I'm just weird like that. You know that.

Comment: focus and do the necessary, stop fighting.

Comment: @RiggsFolly you dont see it in my question because when i put it in the question stack overflow didnt allow it for some reason so i had to remove it

Comment: @TheEkhoedOne I think it was because it wasn't in a code block so it was rendered as it would have been HTML. You need to format code blocks. You should edit the question with your exact code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks Additionally Riggs fixed your `echo` syntax which was incorrect and would have caused issues.

Comment: @TheEkhoedOne Use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49708531/edit to edit your question.

Comment: @dean Who do you think is fighting? Not me an Funky I hope

Comment: @dean "Fighting"? huh?? Riggs, did I miss something here? Did I went and pull out my "Golden Gloves" or you without me/you knowing? Wow, I must be losing it.

Comment: ha haa haa haa haa  you guys are truly funny, but please know that programming is not easy for some of us , please go easy when we ask a self explanatory question.

Comment: @dean I dont see any question that you asked. Did I miss something. And you look like a Senior Programmer to me

Comment: @dean about your *"please go easy when we ask a self explanatory question"* - Oh, so you think it's self-explanatory, I see. Well, I have news for you; it isn't and isn't *black & white*. You should think before acting. Same thing goes for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708755/php-mysql-update-script-not-working#comment86431212_49708755) you left in another question.

Comment: @dean Funk and I just crack the odd joke now and again to relieve the boredom

Comment: @RiggsFolly  may be you did.

Comment: Well, I won't argue with a senior/pro.